# wso2 esb how reuse a portion of code

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a number of sequences and they all work fine. Now realized that in almost all of them , I have repeating code which could be potentially reused . Mostly a few database calls and logging are repeating in every sequence. Only just some parameters changes. Its not business logic , mostly audit and logging stuff.So its good to resue them.
How can i put them somewhere together and reuse them? What is the way to achieve it?Can another sequence do it? Or any other better ways?

I can put the variables in context and read it from that piece of code.

Answer (score 3):

You can create [Sequence Templates](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI630/Working+with+Templates) and use the Mediator [Call Template](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI630/Call+Template+Mediator) within your sequences.

So you can always call the templates and reuse their sequences.

Comment: @Jocket and even you can call a (reusable) sequence in a sequence